# why laravel automatically logout user after some time when I run two ajax calls

Tags: php, laravel, redis, laravel-5

I have two pages to test real-time communication: "client1" and "client2". Both pages running different ajax call (action) with same code every 500ms.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var urlBase = "<?php echo Request::root(); ?>"

        $(function(){

              function requestData1() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: urlBase + '/session/ajaxData1',
                    success: function(point) {

                        setTimeout(requestData1, 500);    
                    },
                    cache: false
                });
              }

              requestData1();

        });
    </script>
```

In my controller, I just pass data to redis.

```
public function ajaxData1()
{
    header("Content-type: text/json");

    $x = time() * 1000;
    $y = rand(0, 100);

    $ret = array($x, $y);

    $redis = LRedis::connection();
    $arrayJson = array();
    array_push($arrayJson, array('"user"' => 'user2') + array('"data"' => $ret));
    $redis->publish('message1', json_encode($arrayJson));
}
```

After some time Laravel automatically logout me. If I set setTimeout to 2000 everything works well. Why is it happening? Would it be the same when I get data from a real source (device)?

Comment: Are you setting session timeout in particular period of time. if you will be redirected once session timeout happens

Comment: Do you want to run both pages at same time?

Comment: Logout happens after less than minute, I didn't change session settings, it is by default.

Comment: @ IshaS yes,  IshaS.

Comment: If you set session timeout within a minute then it will logout you. And you note anything in the laravel.log ?

Comment: [2015-05-25 06:09:55] production.ERROR: exception 'Predis\Connection\ConnectionException'  .... vendor\predis\predis\src\Connection\AbstractConnection.php:146 .

Answer (score 1):

A solution that worked for me with this issue was to use database session storage.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/session#database-sessions

I haven't had a single forced-logout since, although I didn't spend any time afterwards further investigating the original issue. Life's just too short.

Answer (score 1):

Some times it's occurred for **csrf token**. you have to pass the csrf token with post method.

Please see th example to solve the token related issues.

```
            ajax: {
                url: '{{url("registration/get-list")}}',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
                }
            },
```